# Magento Multi Store themes calling same login.phtml file

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento. Currently i'm developing two ecommerce sites using multi-store option in magento. Both the sites are 90% over, last night when i planned to customize the login page i was shocked. The reason is the changes made in first store login page also reflecting in second store also. The login page is curently calling from 
frontend/default/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Is it possible to give any custom login page? PLz guide me magento experts......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your post with your frontend/ folder structure down to each theme template folder. It might be that you don't have a copy of login.phtml in the second theme. Moreover you should follow templates best practices as:

Always create for a new shop different packaga. So not

```
    frontend/default
```

but

```
frontend/yourcustompackage
```

Always have default theme left as much untouched, as possible. So in the

```
frontend/package/default
```

Should be some basic changes and rules of your package. It means for example in the putting reset.css for all of your themes. Or something like this.

As for me, each store view should have own theme. So, for example, **storeview1**

```
frontend/package/storeview1/
```

There you copy and change files specific for this theme. So, for example, in **default** you might have login.phtml. But you want **storeview1** to have another login.phtml and in **storeview2** it should be the same as in **default**. Therefore you copy the login.phtml from **default** to **storeview1** and change it there. Don't forget to change package and theme in System->Configuration->Design. Package should be change for whole shop and theme should be specified for every store view or left untouched for default.

P.S. [Magento theme fallbacks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy)

P.P.S. Try [this](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento-tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-in-magento-1-4) tutorial or google another one

P.P.P.S. I hope, you got the answer for your question.